# Can I import a non-sandboxed .wsp file at farm level via SharePoint GUI?

Tags: import, solution-package

I'm trying to import the [MetadataWebPart](http://metadatawebpart.codeplex.com/), which comes packaged as a solution, to my site.

Can I achieve this via Central Admin?

Is this even possible without using PowerShell or some other script? Everyone keeps telling me I have to run a script to import it, but I would have thought the GUI would provide this functionality somewhere!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Farm Solutions can only be added via the command line or object model, only sandboxed solutions can be uploaded and deployed through the GUI.

Why this is, is anyone's guess, really - unless someone has a good answer.

(ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544500.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A Sandbox solution can only be deployed to a maximum extent of SiteCollection level scope. You cannot deploy any WSP to a farm using the Sandbox approach.